# How to know whether a symbol represents function or macro?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, symbols, function-composition

I'm writing a macro for function / macro composition (mixed combinations are possible). Inside of the macro I have to treat symbols which represent functions and those that name macros differently. It is because result function must work with any number of arguments (if 'lowest' function in composition can), and I cannot apply `apply` to macros. My question: how to determine what a given symbol represents: function or macro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Macro:

```
CL-USER 8 > (macro-function 'bar)
NIL

CL-USER 9 > (macro-function 'lambda)
#<Function LAMBDA 41100B7E94>
```

Function:

```
CL-USER 15 > (and (fboundp '+)
                  (not (macro-function '+))
                  (not (special-operator-p '+)))
T
```

Comment: When I use `macro-function` with a macro, it returns something like `#<COMPILED-FUNCTION ...>`, so macro is just a special kind of function. Is it so? If they are functions, why cannot we use `apply` with them?

Comment: Thank you for additional example for functions, I was forgetting about special operators! (`if` is useful one in my case).

Comment: @Mark: macros transform source code. Applying a macro would mean runtime source transformations. This is non-trivial.

Comment: @Mark You *can* do `(apply (macro-function '...) ...)` or `(funcall (macro-function '...) ...)`.  E.g., `(funcall (macro-function 'lambda) '(lambda () 42) nil) => #'(LAMBDA () 42)`.  `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1` probably aren't doing anything much different.  The reason that you can't `apply` or `funcall` them directly is that `apply` and `funcall` take function designators ­— functions or symbols with a symbol-function.  `(macro-function 'cond)` may have non-nil, but `(symbol-function 'cond)` is nil, so you can't `(funcall 'cond …)`.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: sure you can funcall the macro function. But that is not what one wants. APPLY does not take a macro, because it just does not work how one might expect it and it makes no sense to design APPLY to have it call the macro function. It's not just that APPLY does not allow it, it's not clear from the view of a language designer how to make it work in a useful way. Think about the interaction with lexical bindings, etc.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Right.  Mark asked, though, "If they [i.e., the values of (macro-function ...)] are functions, why cannot we use apply with them?"  We *can* use apply with the functions, because they are just functions.  We can't use apply with the symbol because the macro-function for the symbol isn't the symbol's symbol-function. I'm not saying that we'd *want* to do this, just explaining that (apply (macro-function ...) ...) works, and that (apply 'name-of-macro ...) doesn't, and why.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: we could easily write an APPLY which does that. But it wouldn't be a useful idea. Macros can't be applied not because APPLY does not allow it, but because the CL designers did not know how to make it work in a useful way. Technically you are right, but there is a deeper reason for it.

Comment: I entirely agree that "it wouldn't be a useful idea," and the justification for why APPLY doesn't work with macro functions is based on language design, but the technical reason that APPLY doesn't "see" the macro function if passed a symbol naming a macro is that a symbol is only a designator for its SYMBOL-FUNCTION, not its MACRO-FUNCTION.  If function designator were defined slightly differently, then APPLY would suddenly start APPLYing macro functions.  It wouldn't be very useful, though.  The point I'm trying to make is about function designators and what they do and don't designate.